# Child View not scrolled inside the ContainerView - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, container-view

Container View is fixed with Bottom half of the screen, On Button click current container view will replace with the new View Controller. Each sub view have a different size in height. Sub view Scroll is not working. I checked with many answers but solutions found. The code is

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *viewController = nil;
    viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
    // lets add it to container view
    [viewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.containerViewController addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the result you'd like to achieve. Which view is meant to be scrolled?

Comment: Include new ViewController inside a ContainerView of height Size 500 which have many button widgets, the hidden portion of the ViewController  can't scroll to upwards mean to visible region on the device.

Comment: But the code you provided only instantiates and shows a childviewcontroller, it does not implement any scrolling. How is it supposed to scroll?

Comment: Thanks for reply I had Solved this issue

Comment: Care to share your solution?